# What's the URL to my blogs (from my home page - which is a "page")

Tags: links, urls, blog

How do I add a link under my home page banner to my blog summary page.  My default page is a "page", not a "post".

http://nealwalters.com on 3.0.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a empty page called "Blog", go in Settings > Reading and select "Blog" as the Posts page.

Then add the "Blog" page in your custom menu (Appearance > Menus). Create a custom menu if you didn't already do so...

Comment: The first sentence worked perfectly.  As soon as I added the new page, it automatically appeared on the menu (what like to know what makes that happen or not happen).   Thus, my Appearance->Menus was all blank, no menus defined.

Comment: if you don't have custom menus defined, TwentyTen will show all page links instead. So if you need to re-arrange page links, or remove some of them from the menu, you'll need to use a custom menu